# XDebug cannot connect to client from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, php-7.4, xdebug-3

I have few docker containers: php, nginx, mariadb, redis, adminer and try to debug some PHP code with PhpStorm and Xdebug.

**Host** (Lenovo T490 laptop):

```
$ hostname
T490


$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.5, build 55c4c88


$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b


$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=neon
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="KDE neon User Edition 5.21"


$ php -v
PHP 7.4.16 (cli) (built: Mar  5 2021 07:54:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.16, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies


$ lsof -i :9003 | grep LISTEN
java    14868 kane   48u  IPv6 401093      0t0  TCP *:9003 (LISTEN)


$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       T490

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

172.17.0.1 foo.pl adm.foo.pl api.foo.pl
```

PhpStorm 2020.3.3 config:

[image]

[image]

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  php-7.4:
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    build: ./docker-images/php-7.4
    image: ap/php:7.4
    container_name: foo-php-7.4
    environment:
      - GITHUB_API_TOKEN=${GITHUB_API_TOKEN}
      - XDEBUG_IDEKEY=${XDEBUG_IDEKEY}
    volumes:
      - ~/.composer-docker/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
      - ~/.gitconfig:/root/.gitconfig
      - ${WORKSPACE_DIR}:/var/www
      - ~/.ssh:/root/ssh:ro
      - ./docker/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

XDebug in DockerFile install via:

```
RUN pecl install xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
```

.env

```
GITHUB_API_TOKEN=
WORKSPACE_DIR=/home/kane/workspace

XDEBUG_IDEKEY=PHPSTORM

COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=yii2fpm
COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.yml
X_LEGACY_GD_LIB=1
PHP_CGI_PASS=php-7.4:9000
NGINX_PORT=80
NGINX_SSL_PORT=443
DB_PORT=3306
ADMINER_PORT=8182
```

xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=xdebug

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.client_host=172.17.0.1
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

After docker-compose up, in container:

```
# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         T490            0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0


# ping T490
PING T490 (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from T490 (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms


# ping 172.17.0.1
PING 172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.145 ms


# telnet 172.17.0.1 9003
Trying 172.17.0.1...


# telnet T490 9003
Trying 127.0.1.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused


# php -v
PHP 7.4.16 (cli) (built: Mar 13 2021 02:52:33) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.16, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

And when I go to http://adm.foo.pl/ (with cookie XDEBUG_SESSION:"PHPSTORM") docker log says:

`NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: 172.17.0.1:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(`

After change xdebug.ini to:

```
zend_extension=xdebug

[xdebug]
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.discover_client_host = yes
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

it says:

`NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 172.18.0.1:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header), localhost:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(`

after add `extra_host` says:

`NOTICE: PHP message: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: host.docker.internal:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(`

Please, help :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How sad ...
Usually I work on Centos7 so I looked for the firewall via `firewall-cmd` instead of `ufw` (on Ubuntu/Debian).

```
$ sudo ufw allow 9003
```

Now everything started working as it should.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does it also work with 172.17.0.1?

Comment: Hm, in container `telnet 172.17.0.1 9003` works. XDebug log says `[Step Debug] INFO: Client host discovered through HTTP header, connecting to 172.18.0.1:9003.
[34] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: 172.18.0.1:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header). :-)`

Comment: Oh, that's `discover_client_host`'s doings, it can't work reliably in Docker. Then, your initial setup was correct too, apart from the `ufw` part.

Comment: I'm getting a little similar issue, but I'm working on Windows.  Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 4):

With Docker on Linux, you can either

1. Use the physical network interface (ens* or eth0 or something similar) IP to connect to the host, or
2. Use this hack to be able to use `host.docker.internal`:
   https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-759737542

Installing `telnet` in the container to check the port's availability is always a good idea, the fact that `172.17.0.1` responds to ping doesn't necessarily mean that it's the host.

Comment: Hi, I add `extra_hosts` to my php service in docker-compose, stop/start containers and install telent. No connection, why?

Answer (score 2):

In my case firewall (ufw) on Ubuntu was not the cause: it was rootless Docker that prevented XDebug inside container from connecting to IDE on Host. XDebug needs a bridged network interface named `br-xxxx` and belonging to same network range as php container. This bridged interface can not be created while in rootless (so only Docker's `docker0` is created). My other objective was to keep using `host.docker.internal` in compose.yml (instead of `192.168.x.x` for ethernet or wifi).

Solution that worked for me:

1. added to php service in `compose.yml`

```
extra_hosts:
      host.docker.internal: host-gateway
```

2. added to `docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini`

```
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
```

3. running docker with *sudo*, e.g. `sudo docker compose up -d`

Taken from here:

- [Docker container has no access to host's interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71018188/docker-container-has-no-access-to-hosts-interfaces)
- [Is it possible to use bridge network when running Docker in Rootless mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73952959/is-it-possible-to-use-bridge-network-when-running-docker-in-rootless-mode)

Answer (score 1):

After spending a couple of hours with this problem, I decided to talk to the `192.168.x.x` IP address of the host, rather than the `172.17.0.1`. It worked.

The exact value for `x.x` can be determined by these steps on Windows 10:

- Start -> Command Prompt (Run as Administrator)
- run the `ipconfig | find "IPv4"` command
- use the value of `192.168...`.

This is how my xdebug config looks like now:

```
xdebug.client_host=192.168.1.110
xdebug.client_port="9003"
xdebug.start_upon_error=yes
xdebug.idekey = "PHPStorm"
xdebug.mode=develop,coverage,debug,profile
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had two values ​​in the following docker-compose.yml configuration, deleting the second one started working again

From

```
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
  - "host.docker.internal:127.0.0.1"
```

To:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

I don't know why my configuration was in this way.