# Docker container has no access to host's interfaces

Tags: docker, networking, network-interface

I'm trying to access the host's network interfaces from inside a Docker container with the host-network option.
For debugging purposes I tried to run a clean `Alpine` container using `docker run --network host --rm -it alpine:3.9`. Running `ip link` returns

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65520 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 62:db:1e:6b:52:fe brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
    link/ether 02:42:9a:e6:96:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I would expect the same result as on my host machine with all the interfaces (`lo`, two wired and one wireless interface, `docker`). Why is that not the case?

**UPDATE** to include various outputs:

`dpkg -l | grep docker`:

```
ii  docker-ce                            5:20.10.12~3-0~raspbian-bullseye armhf        Docker: the open-source application container engine
ii  docker-ce-cli                        5:20.10.12~3-0~raspbian-bullseye armhf        Docker CLI: the open-source application container engine
ii  docker-ce-rootless-extras            5:20.10.12~3-0~raspbian-bullseye armhf        Rootless support for Docker.
```

---

`tail -4 /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
Hardware    : BCM2711
Revision    : d03114
Serial      : 1000000025d45b15
Model       : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.4
```

---

`cat /etc/debian_version`:

```
11.2
```

Comment: If you're running Docker on MacOS or Windows, it runs inside a Linux virtual machine. When running in `--network host` mode you'll see the interfaces of the virtual machine, not of your host.

Comment: @larsks Running on a Raspberry Pi

Comment: Something is screwy. I wonder if you could update your question to include the output of `dpkg -l | grep docker`, `tail -4 /proc/cpuinfo`, and `cat /etc/debian_version`?

Comment: I'm at a loss. For comparison, here's the output of the above on my Pi 4: https://gist.github.com/larsks/63e272e8c64a2d439cbd3fdfc790a0fd

Comment: Any idea what I could possibly do or what could be the issue? I tried reinstalling again. Tried on my Pi 3 and the results are as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241801/discussion-between-larsks-and-5t4cktr4c3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing the command with `sudo` fixes the issue as a workaround.

Executing the `run`-command without `sudo` after a `dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh` installation causes the stated issue where the network interfaces are not available, instead a virtual interface is created.