# Is it possible to use bridge network when running Docker in Rootless mode?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network, docker-daemon

I am given to understand that docker bridge network can't be used anymore when running Docker in rootless mode & i see some mention of this in a few old git discussions. However when i go through the Docker docs for [rootless](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) or [bridge-network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) i don't see any mention of such a restriction.

I see from the docs that one still can use the host-network mode with the below restriction,

> Host network (docker run --net=host) is also namespaced inside RootlessKit.

and with the caveats mentioned [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#networking-errors).

If one can still use the host-network as noted above how about the bridge-network? Can someone help throw some light?

UPDATE (OCT 5, 2022):

This [one](https://thenewstack.io/how-to-run-docker-in-rootless-mode/) seems to indicate rootless docker does NOT support host network by stating the below while Docker's own rootless page doesn't seem to indicate so.

I wish Docker clarified these basic aspects clearly in the docs.

> Doesn’t support –net-host.

Answer (score 3):

Rootless docker is executed in a dedicated network namespace and has no permission for bridge devices in the host network namespace. At least podman (rootless networking) needs a userspace app to proxy network connections from and into the container (slirp4netens).

Comment: Thanks @C1sc0, please bear with my ignorance but what i am not able to understand is if one can still use the host-network mode with those caveats, why can't one use bridge-network mode aswell? What is the underlying problem that prevents such a possibility?  Or is it just a matter of current support not being there with caveats?

Comment: You can use bridge, but not in the host network namespace, for short rootless networking sucks!

Comment: :-) I share your sentiment! On the aspect of not in the host network namespace, basically its similar to the host network mode right? There also we have the same restriction understandably & the docs in the caveat section mention using the `-p` flag to bind...so basically if i understood you right we can use bridge-mode aswell with those same caveats, in which case i wonder why they mention only the host-network mode in the rootless docker docs link i referred above..

Comment: Yes, in your own network ns, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: This [one](https://thenewstack.io/how-to-run-docker-in-rootless-mode/) says rootless docker "Doesn’t support –net-host." But --net-host is basically for host network so i am not sure where they are picking up that info from..